# Get time difference in iOS when in offline mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I have an app which works both offline and online. I have a request from the client to embed a functionality which will disallow the user from using certain functionality after some days, 7 days, for example.

If online I can easily achieve this task by comparing the time-interval between server time.

But in offline mode, this has been a problem. I have tried to achieve this by saving server timestamp in USerDefault and when the app comes in the foreground, compare the current NSDate with the one saved to get time interval. But, what I found is this can be hacked easily by manipulating the date and time in Settings and those functionalities in app works perpetually.

Another solution I have thought is to disable the app if date time is not set to automatically in the setting. But, found that Apple has not disclosed the API to access date and time.

I have searched for other answers on the internet, but could not find the solution to fix this issue. Also, tried some offline game app to check but found that I can change date and time to manipulate their functionality.

So, isn't there any robust solution to fix this issue? Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: Essentially you can't trust the device. You need to ask a server. It is unlikely that the user will keep their device offline forever, so I would suggest that you enable background refresh and use that to check the time/date on a server. If the specified time has elapsed, permanently disable the functionality by setting a value in the keychain. The user may turn off background refresh for your app and keep the device offline while using it, but if someone is that determined then there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, background refresh might be a solution but this can be disabled.

Comment: Another check you can make is for time going backwards. Essentially, store in keychain the latest `Date` you have ever seen and keep updating it every minute or so. If you ever see a `Date` earlier than this then you disable the features.

Comment: Yes, this looks good to track if user has changed date time. This might be a life line.

Answer (score -1):

> you can manage timings on the server through API calls when the user
>   goes offline or log out or something. so you can easily get to know
>   your exact timing and it is also not hackable :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. But, my problem is when app is offline and can't get the current server time. The only way is to check with device time which user can manipulate easily and that's my problem.